# Wrong keyboard layout despite US layout being set in vconsole.conf and 00-keyboard.conf

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, manjaro, keyboard-layout

Some time ago I installed Manjaro Linux and set the keyboard layout to German. Now I bought a new keyboard with a US layout, so I want to change the system keyboard layout to US too. I changed `/etc/vconsole.conf` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`.

The first has the line `KEYMAP=us` and the latter looks as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
      Identifier "system-keyboard"
      MatchIsKeyboard "on"
      Option "XkbLayout" "us"
      Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
```

But anytime I restart, the keyboard layout is reset to DE and I have to correct it using `setxkbmap us`. I thought about putting that command in some start up file but there has to be a root cause somewhere which I'd like to fix

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`. 
(You will need to be root, so use `su`, `sudo` or something comparable.) 
Find the line

```
#Keyboard layout
```

and add or modify the following line as

```
setxkbmap -layout "us" &
```

If you want to add two layouts, for example US and DE, you can do it as:

```
#Keyboard layout    
setxkbmap -layout "us,de" -option grp:alt_shift_toggle &
```

Comment: First of all, thanks! But while that would probably work, it still wouldn't fix the root cause I think, because the wrong keyboard layout has to be set somewhere, I just don't know where. I assume there are some config files which I don't know about